# UPDATE column if column is greater than a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement, sql-update

I have a table with these columns

- `proxy_id` (primary key)
- `proxy` (IP of a proxy)
- `current_requests` (number of current requests the proxy has handled since its `last_cool_down`)
- `total_requests` (number of requests this proxy has fulfilled in its lifetime)
- `last_used` (datetime of last time this proxy was used)
- `last_cool_down` (datetime of last time this proxy was on cooldown)

After I have used a proxy I run this command (obviously with the current date and time, but we will assume the current datetime is `2020-04-28 13:10:03`)

```
UPDATE proxy_table
SET
current_requests = current_requests + 1,
total_requests = total_requests + 1,
last_used = '2020-04-28 13:10:03',
last_cool_down = '2020-04-28 13:10:03'
WHERE proxy_id = 1
```

My issue is I must ALWAYS update `current_requests` and `last_used` no matter what. However, in the above code, it doesn't consider this condition. If `current_requests + 1 == 20`, then `current_requests = 0` and `last_cool_down = '2020-04-28 13:10:03'`. How can I do this?

So essentially something like this

```
UPDATE proxy_table

if (current_requests + 1 == 20) {
    SET current_requests = 0;
    SET last_cool_down = '2020-04-28 13:10:03';
else {
    SET current_requests = current_requests + 1;
}

SET total_requests = total_requests + 1;
SET last_used = '2020-04-28 13:10:03';
WHERE proxy_id = 1;
```

I want to do this in one sql statement, rather than running 2 statements. My attempt at this didn't work:

```
UPDATE proxy_table
SET
    CASE
        WHEN current_requests + 1 = 20
        THEN current_requests = 0, last_cool_down = '2020-04-28 13:10:03' 
        ELSE current_requests = current_requests + 1
    total_requests = total_requests + 1,
    last_used = '2020-04-28 13:10:03'
WHERE
proxy_id = 1
```

Comment: use `case` statement.

Comment: @zealous I tried it (edited my answer) but I couldnt get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expressions to set the column values dependent on the current value of `current_requests`:

```
UPDATE proxy_table
SET
last_cool_down = CASE WHEN current_requests = 19 THEN '2020-04-28 13:10:03'
                      ELSE last_cool_down
                 END,
current_requests = CASE WHEN current_requests = 19 THEN 0 
                        ELSE current_requests + 1
                   END,
total_requests = total_requests + 1,
last_used = '2020-04-28 13:10:03'
WHERE proxy_id = 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMXjJYZ4853RS4RXad64AS/2)

Comment: My question to this is, will the `last_cool_down` ever get updated? Because `current_requests` gets updated to `0` before `last_cool_down` does

Comment: This isn't working for me. It updates `last_used` and `total_requests` but nothing else.

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov my mistake, you were right about the update of `last_cool_down`. I forgot MySQL's *feature* which is not standard SQL. Anyway, I've created a demo which shows the corrected query working. See my edit.

Comment: I do that but it still doesn't work. Only updates `last_cool_down` and `current_requests`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov if you've put the query in correctly there's no way that `current_requests` will not update either to `0` or `current_requests+1`

Answer (score 0):

MySql has this special *feature* to use the changed column values in expressions of the `UPDATE` statement, so the order of the assignments must be like this:

```
UPDATE proxy_table
SET last_cool_down = CASE WHEN current_requests + 1 = 20 THEN '2020-04-28 13:10:03' ELSE last_cool_down END,
    current_requests = CASE WHEN current_requests + 1 = 20 THEN 0 ELSE current_requests + 1 END,
    total_requests = total_requests + 1, 
    last_used = '2020-04-28 13:10:03'
WHERE proxy_id = 1
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. It updates `last_used` and `total_requests` but nothing else.

Comment: The code that you say that is not working is exactly the same as the answer that you accepted, but it was posted first, long before the other answer was edited (it was edited because I posted my answer with the correct code as you can see in the comment).